# Reference request: complete, rigorous proof of compactification of moduli spaces of flow lines in Morse homology?

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, morse-theory

The result I'm looking for can be stated as follows (taken from Hutchings' notes):

[image]

Here the moduli spaces are referring to the spaces of flow lines of the negative gradient flow induced by the Morse function $f$ and Riemannian metric $g$.

Where can I find a proof of this theorem that is complete and rigorous? I have searched for days on relevant material and here are some of those which I've checked out:

- M. Hutchings, *Lecture notes on Morse homology*: He states the theorem above but does not seem to have gone into the details of the proof.
- M. Schwarz, *Morse Homology*: I have tried to read it, but it is way too long and technical. In particular, I got stuck with the theory of coherent orientation used there and hence asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678634/proof-that-morse-complex-is-a-complex-using-coherent-orientation) (with no reply yet).
- M. Audin & M. Damian, *Morse Theory and Floer Homology*: Although this book contains an acceptable proof in the case of $k=1$ above (minus orientation issues), their results are different from the above theorem in the following way. In their approach, they use a so-called "pseudo gradient field" which is not necessarily a gradient field but whose flow looks like a gradient flow. Thus the objects of study there are not exactly Morse–Smale systems in the sense of the above theorem.
- J. Weber, *The Morse-Witten complex via dynamical systems* (available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411465)): The proofs are not complete. In his proof of gluing (Theorem 3.9), he did not explain why the constructed fixed point $p_t$ is smooth in $t$, and I can't see why this is true from his proof. Also, the proof of coherence is confusing. (By the way, can someone who has already carefully read this paper explain these points? That would solve my problem!)
- Banyaga & Hurtubise, *Lectures on Morse Homology*: This book seems to avoid the gluing procedure.

Any help is deeply appreciated!

Cross-posted on [MathStackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3680602/reference-request-complete-rigorous-proof-of-compactification-of-moduli-spaces).

Comment: The most complete write-up I know is due to Wehrheim [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0713).

Comment: Which is to say, the statement made by Hutchings is not exactly true (and this problem later hunted Cohen, Jones and Segal). The structure of a manifold with corners is not canonical unless an assumption is added.